# How Can I find the points outside a polygon in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I had plotted a polygon, and used inpolygon matlab function to find the in and on points with respect to the polygon, however, the inpolygon matlab function did not give me logical results, how can i find accurately the points outside the polygon?
This is my code.

```
nb_lignes = size(image_in1,1);
nb_colonnes = size(image_in1,2);
[Xq,Yq] = 
meshgrid(1:nb_colonnes,1:nb_lignes);%grille du cube


[in,on] = inpolygon(Xq,Yq,X1,Y1);
out= ~inpolygon(Xq,Yq,X1,Y1);
f=numel(Xq(in));
p=numel(Xq(on));
figure

plot(X1,Y1) % polygon
axis equal

hold on
plot(Xq(in),Yq(in),'r+') % points inside
plot(Xq(~in),Yq(~in),'bo') % points outside
plot(out,'y')
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: How did you create a post full of “enter code here” template text, and decide “yes, that looks good, I don’t need to improve anything”?

Comment: When you draw points using markers, all the markers overlap. Your blue area is formed by overlapping circles that also overlap the red markers. Try zooming into your plot.

Comment: You are right, it was the problem of the overlapping shapes, when I changed the shapes it gave accurate results. Thanks a lot for your help.